# middle align svg with inline text

Tags: css

I have a simple svg image with some inline text as pasted [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRrdbE). How to middle-align both the text and the icon vertically? I tried usual ways to middle align such as setting negative `martin-top`, use `table-cell` but no luck.

HTML:

```
<div class="ImageLabel__label___Yb88q">
    <i class="ImageLabel__icon___bFeGT">
        <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
            <title>email</title>
            <path d="..."></path>
        </svg>
    </i>
    john@gmail.com
</div>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   svg {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    Vertical-align: middle;   /*----- Add this property in your svg -----*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't add `margin-top` because it needs a `float` value. You can do it like this:

```
svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
```